# What is the best approach to update a database table based on the result of non transactional task

Tags: sql, transactions

I have a database table that each row represents a single Task. The row also contains a field [Completed] which should be true if the task has been completed successfully or false on every other occasion.

Lets assume that the Task is represented by the function below:

```
bool Task(int TaskId);
```

which returns true on Success of the task and false on failure.

What is the best way to update Completed field of Task Table based on the result of Task?

A have thought to approaches:

A.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

UPDATE TASKS SET Completed = 1 WHERE TaskId=@SpecificTask

if (Task(SpecificTask))
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
else
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

B.

```
if (Task(SpecificTask))
    UPDATE TASKS SET Completed = 1 WHERE TaskId=@SpecificTask
```

How can I avoid the task succeeding but database update cannot be completed?

Comment: Maybe it's Before Coffee for me, but until the transaction is committed -- the boolean function will return false, unless you're reading dirty data (READ UNCOMMITTED).

Comment: The boolean function is not database related. It does something not related to the Database. Consider the code psevdo-code.

Answer (score 1):

```
begin tran
if (Task(SpecificTask))
    UPDATE TASKS SET Completed = 1 WHERE TaskId=@SpecificTask
commit
```

Don't use rollback for a failing task. It has nasty performance and I'd avoid it for semantic reasons as well. Your function did succeed after all, so the tran should commit orderly.

Comment: The thing is that bool Task() is not related to the Database at all. I consider the scenario below:
1) Starting Transaction.
2) Starting Task.
3) While Task Still Running - Communication to the SQL Server is lost.
4) Task Finished Successfully.
5) Database won't be updated accordingly. I think that there is no way to execute the Task and Update the database in an atomic step.

Comment: You are right. If the connection is lost, you have lost. You yould make the task write a success log to some file which gets picked up later.